# Why does a lens hood plus built in flash cause shadows on the photo?

Tags: popup-flash, shadows

Why is there a shadow on the photo taken with Canon DSLR camera with lens hood and built in flash?

Comment: A situation where you need a lens hood and a flash but _don't_ need a speedlight. hmmm. Not sure about that one. The only thing I can think of is using the camera as white light trigger while shooting outdoors with off camera fill. But then, how would it be dark enough in the subject area for the winky flash to have a contribution? I feel like we are being trolled here

Answer (score 7):

[image: shadow monster]

***Lens hoods*** attached to super-zoom kit lenses **contain a shadow monster** that is released when exposed to light from the built-in flash. **Remove the hood** to avoid letting the monster escape into your photos.

---

[@mattdm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/100128/75526), [@dpollitt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45617/75526), [@YaoBoLu](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45628/75526), and [@JohnGleeson](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/72290/75526) are all correct. Light from the built-in flash hitting the lens hood casts a shadow. If the lens is large enough, it may cast a shadow on its own without a hood. You have many options to try avoiding the problem:

- Don't use flash.
- Remove the hood.
- Use a smaller lens.
- Zoom in or out until the shadow isn't visible.
- Re-orient the camera so the shadow doesn't fall on a foreground object.
- Use a larger on-camera flash.
- Use an off-camera flash.
- Point the flash at a wall or the ceiling.  (Some built-in flashes tilt.)
- Use a diffuser to soften the shadow.
- Use a bounce card.

Here's a before and after using a business-card bounce. A larger card would have been easier to use. The bounce was pretty weak, but not hopeless. Used +3 EC to compensate. (The [2-cent flash diffuser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8uQu.jpg) works [better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yybJk.jpg).)

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: I realize this is comical and that the image does show what is happening, a real explanation being added after the funny part would make this a much stronger answer.  Someone might not catch what is actually happening in the picture.

Comment: It could be insincere or it could be that they are wondering why the built in flash doesn't avoid this.  It's hard to tell from such a short question.  It doesn't really seem troll like, so I'm not sure what their intent was.  Generally best to assume good faith, though yes, it is likely to be closed as a dupe anyway, but those may get merged in to the existing, so it's still good for any answer to actually work and there's no problem with humor in a decent answer.

Comment: I see the monster in both pictures! Look at his demonic red ears.

Comment: Eeyore is already sad.

Answer (score 2):

Because the built-in flash is too close to the camera body, and therefore the lens blocks its light in the frame, causing a shadow.

The lens hood can't be made smaller, or else it would not be effective. And the pop-up flash can't be made to move further away without making it more bulky, more fragile, or both.

So, given that, this is kind of a case of "Doctor, it hurts when I do this..." (Doctor says: "Well, don't do that.") Take off the hood, or else use a hotshoe or remote flash.

Answer (score 2):

The [2-cent flash diffuser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8uQu.jpg), made by wrapping a piece of paper around the built in flash.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

[Sample images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yybJk.jpg):

[image: sample1]
[image: sample2]

Comment: It improves the result, but there is still a shadow there, quite pronounced, for me at least.